# NoSQL records need a new field to be added

Tags: json, nosql

I want to use NoSQL update to change in the record some sub-json data to have one more boolean field there. So for example I have in each record such data:

```
{ "some": { "some_nested": { "a": true, "b" : 23, .... } } }
```

I want to add to `"some_nested"` one more field called `"new_field"` so that it would look like this:

```
{ "some": { "some_nested": { "new_field" : true, "a": true, "b" : 23, .... } } }
```

that is to say I should keep the former structure and add just one more data to some sub-json.

I have no skills of NoSQL please help what is the correct command.